# Trying to convert from pandas `append` to `concat` not working

Tags: pandas

Following a tutorial and it has this code:

```
RULColumn = pd.Series(dtype='float64')    
for unit in range(turboFanData['unitNum'].iloc[-1]):
    turboFanUnit = turboFanData[turboFanData['unitNum'] == unit+1]
    # This following line generates the warning:
    RULColumn = RULColumn.append(turboFanUnit['cycles'].iloc[::-1].copy() - 1)
```

It give this warning:

```
RULColumn = RULColumn.append(turboFanUnit['cycles'].iloc[::-1].copy() - 1)
main.py:34: FutureWarning: The series.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

Apparently `concat` and `append` are equivalent, but this does not work:

```py
import pandas as pd

    ... (same as before)
    # This is how I am trying to use concat instead of append:
    RULColumn = pd.concat(RULColumn, turboFanUnit['cycles'].iloc[::-1].copy() - 1)
```

Comment: do you need `RULColumn = pd.concat([RULColumn, turboFanUnit['cycles'].iloc[::-1].copy() - 1])` ?

Comment: @jezrael, yes, why do you ask?

Comment: because thinking if typo - forget for `[]`